# PHP - Paths of several files to one field in the database

Tags: php, mysql, database, image, file

I have a form with a file selection. I want the paths of the selected files to be saved after a decimal point into a single field in the database. The problem I have is that only the first selected file is saved, and I want to save all the decimal places in one field. Eg uploads / 1.png, uploads / 2.png, uploads / 3.png etc ..  ( IN PHP )

How can I achieve this?

Code:

```
if( !empty($_FILES['files']['name'][0]) ) {
    //Zmienne formularza
    $files = $_FILES['files'];
    $thumb = $_FILES['thumbnail'];
    $text = $_POST['add-project_text'];
    $h2text = $_POST['add-project_name'];

    //Dozwolone pliki
    $allowed = array('txt', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif', 'svg', 'psd');

    foreach ($files['name'] as $position => $file_name) {
        //Wyciągnięcie parametrów z plików
        $file_tmp = $files['tmp_name'][$position];
        $file_size = $files['size'][$position];
        $file_error = $files['error'][$position];

        //Dla zdjęć ( wyciągniecie rozszerzenia pliku )
        $file_ext = explode('.', $file_name);
        $file_ext = strtolower(end($file_ext));
        $datenow = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        //Dla miniaturki
        $file_extThumb = explode('.', $thumb['name']);
        $file_extThumb = strtolower(end($file_extThumb));

       //Jeżeli rozszerzenie jest prawidłowe
       if (in_array($file_ext, $allowed)) {

       //Jeżeli plik nie ma żadnych błędów
       if($file_error === 0) {
           //Jeżeli plik nie jest większy niż 15MB
           if($file_size <= 15728640) {
               //Jeżeli folder uzytkownika istnieje
               if(file_exists('uploads/' . $_SESSION['login'])) {

               } else {
                  //Jeżeli nie, stwórz go.
                  mkdir('uploads/' . $_SESSION['login']);
               }

               //Dla zdjęć
               $file_new_name = uniqid('', true) . '.' . $file_ext;
               //Dla miniaturki
               $file_new_nameThumb = 'Thumbnail.' . uniqid('', true) . '.' . $file_extThumb;

               //Dla zdjęć
               $file_destination = 'uploads/' . $_SESSION['login'] . '/' . $file_new_name;
               //Dla miniaturki
               $file_destinationThumb = 'uploads/' . $_SESSION['login'] . '/' . $file_new_nameThumb;
               //Jeżeli wszystko jest ok, przenieś go do odpowiedniego folderu
               if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file_destination)) {

                   //Jeżeli wszystko jest ok, przenieś go do odpowiedniego folderu
                   if(move_uploaded_file($thumb['tmp_name'], $file_destinationThumb)) {
                        $sqlSTM = $dbh->prepare(" INSERT INTO projects (post_content, post_images, post_image, post_date) VALUES (:post_content, :post_images, :post_image, :post_date) ");
                        $sqlSTM->bindParam(":post_content", $text, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $sqlSTM->bindParam(":post_images", $file_destination, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $sqlSTM->bindParam(":post_image", $file_destinationThumb, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $sqlSTM->bindParam(":post_date", $datenow, PDO::PARAM_STR);

                        $_SESSION['UploadedSuc'] = 'Udało się! Dodano nowy projekt!';
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $file_size_r = $file_size / 1000000;

                echo 'Wystąpił błąd przy dodawaniu pliku, prawdopodobnie plik jest za duży. Maksymalna wielkość pliku to 15MB. Twój plik: ' . number_format($file_size_r, 0) . 'MB';
            }
        } else {
            echo 'Wystąpił błąd przy dodawaniu pliku: ' . $file_error;
        }
    } else {
        echo 'To rozszerzenie: <b>' . $file_ext . '</b> jest niedozwolone.';
    }
}
```

I want the paths of these files to be saved under a variable ":post_images".

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
// Saving the urls
$post_images = json_encode([$url1, $url2, $url3]);

// And for getting the urls
$post_images = json_decode($data['urls']);
```

Comment: Sorry, but i don't understand.. In variable **$file_destination**  I have a string ie the path of the file I have chosen. This variable goes to bindParam **$sqlSTM->bindParam(":post_images", $file_destination, PDO::PARAM_STR);**  I want this string to be completely written to the database .. and there only the first path of the first file only writes.

Comment: For example. In **$file_destination** is there is a string "uploads/1.png", "uploads/2.png", "uploads/3.png"...  and And only the first element ie "uploads/1png" that saves to the database...

Comment: @nielot You could transform your $file_destination variable to an array ex: [path/img1.jpg, path/img2.jpg] and json_encode the array. Then save the encoded data to your database. (Now you have all urls neatly saved as json string in your database), and upon retrieving your urls, you simply decode them (json_decode), now you have your array of urls available for usage. By doing this, you save yourself the hassle of exploding on "," to get an array of urls.

Comment: Sorry for replying so late. It still do not work .. only one entry is entered into the database .. eg $ file_destination has this: ['uploads / 1.png'], ['uploads / 2.png'], ['uploads / 3. Png] .. and the only first element save into the database, is: ['uploads / 1.png']...

Comment: I do this:   **$a1 = array($file_destination); $a1 = json_encode($a1);**

Comment: @nielot Your array should look something like: `[ 0 => 'uploads/1.png', 1 => 'uploads/2.jpg'];` you can then json encode & decode this array correctly.